# Automatic Invoice on CiviCrm

Tags: civimember

My question is, can the Member get an automatic invoice directly from CiviCRM once he renewals his membership even if he didn't pay online, or he chooses to pay via bank transfer?

Comment: What exactly do you need the invoice for? Are invoicing organizations for their memberships? There is a way to create membership invoices for renewals.

Comment: Hi, yes this is what we want, to send an automatic invoice to members once they renew their memberships and even if they ask to pay via bank transfer

Comment: Do your members always paid by bank transfer? Or are there also other ways of paying the membership fee.

Comment: Yes, most of them pay via credit cards and the rest Via bank transfer.

Comment: Do you really need an invoice, in the sense of a document with a sequence number, VAT number, VAT etc...? Or is a letter/e-mail with instructions to pay also sufficient? You might also have a look at CiviBanking for importing bank files and registering payments and renewals as soon a payment comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Abdalla, Welcome to CiviCRM SE. Yes, Member will get the receipt when a payment is processed from payment processor or bank transfer. CiviCRM sends the receipt to the user if the payment is complete. CCiviCRM also lets you generate invoice which includes tax details for the contribution(payment), this is not send automatically to user by CiviCRM.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks, Pradeep for your reply, but my question is that I need the member to receive the Invoice once he renewal his membership, not only once he pays the membership fee online! ( i mean if he decided to renew his membership and pay via Bank transfer

Comment: Yes the renewal receipt is also send once the payment for renewal is received. If you renewing membership manually via backend form then the form allows you to send email to  receipt

Comment: So that's mean, no invoice till we receive the money!!!

Comment: CiviCRM is not really good in invoicing. At one of my clients we create completed contributions in civicrm for the membership. Then export those the accounting system and the accountant is going to create and send invoices (and do the follow up). Most members pay their invoice as soon as they received it. In CiviCRM, the membership is extended.